# Catching all timeout exception and logging them to Elmah with more context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have multiple web apps built using ASP.NET MVC 4/5. All of them use Elmah for error handling, also our apps get a lot of timeout errors.

Here is how it gets logged:

> The wait operation timed out
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>
> The wait operation timed out

[image]

I want to log something more meaningful in the subject. Something like - "DB Timeout - SP name" which can be more useful, otherwise I would have to open each of these log, read the stack trace and then debug.

Now to achieve this I know I can write a custom exception, catch all db timeout exception and re-throw my custom exception with the stored procedure name.

But that would require me to write a same piece of try catch in each of my service layer code.

Is there any other better way using which this could be tackled ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible through ELMAH's error filtering feature. I've utilized this to [remove sensitive form data from elmah.io](http://docs.elmah.io/remove-sensitive-form-data/).

In short you need to hook into the ErrorLog_Filtering event (see [ELMAH's documentation](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering)):

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    var httpContext = args.Context as HttpContext;
    if (httpContext != null && args.Exception is TimeoutException)
    {
        var error = new Error(args.Exception, httpContext);
        error.Message = "DB Timeout - SP name";
        ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error);
        args.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

This method is called everytime ELMAH wants to log an error in your error log. If there's a HTTP context and the thrown exception is a TimeoutException (just using this as an example and you will need to replace this with your DB exception), we create a new error from the thrown exception. The new error automatically gets all of the info from the thrown error. Log the new error through the Log method and dismiss the original error with the wrong message by calling Dismiss() on the event args.